# How to properly use list_append to keep values unique in DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

In the following code, the contacts are added to the contacts attribute even if they already exists in it. But I would like to prevent duplicates because it would make no sense to have the same contact twice.
I tried to use contains with no success.
Do you have any idea on how I could manage that?

```
const contact = event.contactId
const params = {
    TableName,
    Key: {
        userId: event.userId
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    UpdateExpression: 'set #contacts = list_append((if_not_exists(#contacts, :empty_list), :contact)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#contacts': 'contacts'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':contact': [contact],
        ':empty_list': []
    }
} // TODO: Must be unique IDs

dynamodb.update(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        callback(err)
    } else {
        console.log(data)
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            message: "Successfully added contact " + contact,
            updatedContacts: data.Attributes.contacts
        }
        callback(null, response)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you need to use a `Set` instead of a `List` of contact IDs to achieve what you want *in only one call to DynamoDB*. That being said, there are two ways to accomplish it with a `Set`, and it is possible to do this with a list if you’re okay making a read before you save the new contact.

**Option 1**

DynamoDB supports using [`ADD`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD) for Set attributes, and a Set will guarantee that no duplicate IDs are present. You can use `ADD` to silently succeed without causing a duplicate contact using this method.

If you use `ADD`, your update expression would be

```
ADD #contacts :contact
```

This method will work whether your contact IDs are a Number or a String.

**Option 2**

Use a [condition expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) to prevent the contact from being added if it’s already present. DynamoDB has a `contains(path, operand)` function that supports String and StringSet attributes.

You would use the same update expression as in Option 1, and the condition expression for this would be

```
attribute_not_exists(#contacts) OR NOT contains(#contacts, :contact)
```

This option will let you know that the contact is already present because if the contact is already present, you will get a `ConditionalCheckFailed` response from DynamoDB.

**Option 3**

Begin by reading the current `List` of contacts from DynamoDB. Verify in your application that you will not be adding a duplicate. If the new contact would be a duplicate, then you have nothing more to do. If the contact would be a duplicate, then you can save the updated contact list using these expressions

```
UpdateExpression: “SET #contacts = :updatedContacts”
ConditionExpression: "#contacts = :oldContacts”
```

In this case, `:oldContacts` should be the list that you initially read from DynamoDB.

The drawback of this approach is that  a concurrent update to the list could cause a valid update to fail.

**Option 4**

This is the most involved of all the approaches. You can add a `version` attribute to the items in the table, and like Option 3, you first read the item, verify that the new contact is not a duplicate, and then make a conditional write. However, in this case, your conditional write would include

```
UpdateExpression: “SET #contacts = :updatedContacts, #version = :newVersion”,
ConditionExpression: “#version = :oldVersion”
```

This is known as [Optimistic Locking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html). While not part of the JavaScript SDK, it is simple enough to implement on your own in this case.

**Concluding Notes**

You should be aware that Options 3 and 4 won’t work for a global table which is being concurrently update in multiple regions. Option 2 may fail to inform you of an attempt to add a duplicate under those same conditions, but it will still guarantee that there are no duplicates present. ([Global Tables are eventually consistent between regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_HowItWorks.html), so the condition expression may evaluate to true for one region, but not for another.)

Finally, you may find the [Comparison Operator and Function Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html) helpful if you want more details about any of the functions that are available to use in a condition or update expression.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and comprehensive answer. However, I would rather use option 1 but I am not sure how to use it since DynamoDB doesn't seem to handle empty sets. My first thought was to create one when creating my user's profile.

Comment: That would be a simple and effective way to deal with the empty set limitation.

Comment: I guess so but I don't know how. As I can't create an empty set, how can I declare one on user's profile creation? It would need to be empty since an user needs to be created before adding any contacts.

Comment: Further review of the documentation indicates that empty sets should not be a problem for you. When using `ADD` the set is not required to already exist.

Comment: legend just want to add, further reading, because you going to error on that ConditionalExpression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053595/how-do-i-conditionally-insert-an-item-into-a-dynamodb-table-using-boto3