# Conditionally insert an item into a dynamodb table using boto3 Error Attribute name is a reserved keyword

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am calling this function to put items if an item(state) does not exist, something which I am referring from here : [How do I conditionally insert an item into a dynamodb table using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053595/how-do-i-conditionally-insert-an-item-into-a-dynamodb-table-using-boto3) ..

```
    def put_items_if_doesnt_exist():
      dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')
      try:
          table = dynamodb.Table('awssolutions-ssm-hybrid-table')
          response = table.put_item(
          Item={
                  'name':'Execution',
                  'state': 'Locked',
              },
          ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(state) AND attribute_not_exists(name)'
          )
      except ClientError as e:
          # Ignore the ConditionalCheckFailedException
          if e.response['Error']['Code'] != 'ConditionalCheckFailedException':
              raise
```

Problem here is that the state is a reserved word and therefore it fails with the error :

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: Invalid ConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: state
```

**Any suggestions to handle this ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where [`ExpressionAttributeNames`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html) come in, they let you use reserved names. You just add a placeholder with the `#` prefix and in the `ExpressionAttributeNames` parameter specify its value.

```py
    def put_items_if_doesnt_exist():
      dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')
      try:
          table = dynamodb.Table('awssolutions-ssm-hybrid-table')
          response = table.put_item(
          Item={
                  'name':'Execution',
                  'state': 'Locked',
              },
          ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(#state) AND attribute_not_exists(#name)',
          ExpressionAttributeNames={"#state": "state", "#name": "name"}
          )
      except ClientError as e:
          # Ignore the ConditionalCheckFailedException
          if e.response['Error']['Code'] != 'ConditionalCheckFailedException':
              raise
```

Comment: Cool, works for me!